# org.auraframework.throwable.quickfix.DefinitionNotFoundException: No APPLICATION named markup:

Tags: lightning-apps, lightning-experience, summer-17, unexpectedexception

We're getting an error in Lightning embedded VF page (while loading page) since yesterday. It appeared in Dev. org (for testing) we installed this managed package for testing. Is this a known issue? It appears only in summer 17, in spring 17 works fine.

An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 1433379882-18230 (-1365908992)

org.auraframework.throwable.quickfix.DefinitionNotFoundException: No APPLICATION named markup://ourAppnamespace:OurApp found
at org.auraframework.impl.DefinitionServiceImpl.getHelper(DefinitionServiceImpl.java:1504)
at org.auraframework.impl.DefinitionServiceImpl.compileDef(DefinitionServiceImpl.java:1623)
at org.auraframework.impl.DefinitionServiceImpl.compileDE(DefinitionServiceImpl.java:1001)
at org.auraframework.impl.DefinitionServiceImpl.getDefinition(DefinitionServiceImpl.java:238)
at aura.impl.util.LightningOutUtils.isLightningOutApplication(LightningOutUtils.java:49)
at aura.impl.util.LightningOutUtils.isLightningOutAppRequest(LightningOutUtils.java:77)
at ui.services.facades.CoreLightningOutFacadeImpl.isLightningOutAppRequest(CoreLightningOutFacadeImpl.java:26)
at ui.aura.util.impl.AuraServletsUtilImpl.isAuraDomain(AuraServletsUtilImpl.java:314)
at ui.aura.util.impl.AuraServletsUtilImpl.verifyAuraDomain(AuraServletsUtilImpl.java:322)
at ui.aura.util.impl.AuraServletsUtilImpl.preAuraRequest(AuraServletsUtilImpl.java:93)
at aura.impl.sfdc.bean.adapter.SFDCAuraServletsUtilAdapter.actionServletGetPre(SFDCAuraServletsUtilAdapter.java:75)
at org.auraframework.http.AuraServlet.doGet(AuraServlet.java:227)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
at org.eclipse.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1693)
at system.filter.AuraDomainRedirectFilter.doFilter(AuraDomainRedirectFilter.java:81)
....

Anyone experiencing this? appreciate help on any clue. could be a great help.
Thanks.

Comment: Updated with additional details.

Comment: we are facing same issue. You can raise issue with Salesforce. Please post if salesforce give any Solution. We have raised this issue with salesforce and if we find any solution we will post it here.

Comment: Hi @ManjotSingh try creating  [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm) SF example in app installed org. and run it once. After that all failed pages started to work for us. But this is not an acceptable solution. Waiting for SFDC to come back, it seems like their summer 17 got some issue in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @pasan Eeriyagama i got reply from Salesforce. They have appiled a Patch and problem is resolved. So pages are working on Summer 17 preview.

Comment: Hi @Manjot Singh have they fixed in your instance? can you please post the link to resolved issue if it's available publicly.  I checked in a new summer 17 instance, but I still see the error popping up in ours.

Comment: @PasanEeriyagama it is not publicaly available. But Salesforce said that they had made an update in summer 17 preview.

Comment: Seems fixed now.