# Lightning Components in Managed Package throwing errors until a Lightning App is create via Console

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, lightning-experience

I have a managed package with some Lightning Components and a Lightning Tab. When I create a new org (Partner Developer Edition) from Environment Hub it will already have "My Domain" set and deployed, so this is not an issue.

Now, if I install my Beta Package to this PDE org, my Lightning tab is visible but is throwing the below error:

> No COMPONENT named markup://My_Namespace:My_Component found

However, and this is a weird part, if I just go to Developer Console and create an empty Lightning App, and preview it, my Lightning Tab starts working normally. This has now been reproduced in 2 separate orgs.

Does anybody have any idea what is happening? I'm completely baffled.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue with summer 17 preview orgs. But today everything started working fine. We have raised a case with salesforce and they told us they had fixed this issue with new update. If you are still facing this issue .I think you should raise a case with saleforce. Here is a another user facing same issue :-
[org.auraframework.throwable.quickfix.DefinitionNotFoundException: No APPLICATION named markup:](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177502/org-auraframework-throwable-quickfix-definitionnotfoundexception-no-application?noredirect=1#comment268927_177502)